# Using Oracle Sequence in SQL Loader?

Tags: oracle10g, sql-loader

I am using `SEQUENCE` keyword in SQL Loader control file to generate primary keys. But for a special scenario I would like to use `Oracle sequence` in the control file. The [Oracle documentation for SQL Loader](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_field_list.htm#sthref1274) doesn't mentioned anything about it. does SQL Loader support it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, but you can assign the sequence via the on insert trigger unless this is a direct path load.

Comment: Thank you @REW. I am not using direct path load.

Answer (score 4):

I have managed to load without using the dummy by  the switching the sequence to be the last column as in :

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'data.csv'
APPEND INTO TABLE my_data
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(
    name char,
    ID "MY_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL"
)
```

and  data.csv would be like:

```
"dave"
"carol"
"tim"
"sue"
```

Comment: You have to add `TRAILING NULLCOLS` to the control file.

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully used a sequence from my `Oracle 10g database` to populate a primary key field during an `sqlldr` run:

Here is my data.ctl:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'data.csv'
APPEND INTO TABLE my_data
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(
  ID "MY_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL",
  name char
)
```

and my data.csv:

```
-1, "dave"
-1, "carol"
-1, "tim"
-1, "sue"
```

For some reason you have to put a dummy value in the CSV file even though you'd figure that `sqlldr` would just figure out that you wanted to use a sequence.